# Ubuntu server running Apache and Webmin is directing http://[ip] to Webmin

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, webmin

I have a server on AWS running the latest Ubuntu 16.04, Apache and Webmin. This is a hobby only server, so security is not a concern. I have two virtual servers configured in Apache - hobbysite.mydomain.com and webmin.mydomain.com. Webmin is configured on port 10000 and accessible on [ip]:10000 and through webmin.mydomain.com with this directive:

```
ServerName webmin.mydomain.com
ProxyPass / http://localhost:10000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:10000/
<Proxy *>
    allow from all
</Proxy>
```

My hobbysite.mydomain.com is working properly as well by redirecting to the correct folder. My problem is that http://[ip] is also re directing to Webmin. I would only like it accessible through port 10000 and webmin.mydomain.com only. Is there a configuration set in Webmin or Apache that would produce this behavior?